# light switch use now affects other lights

Tags: wiring, lighting

I changed my pendant light in the bathroom, this is what it looked like when i took the cover off (i choccyboxed off those 3 cables)
I put the new light fitting on and rewired exactly the way it was, and now it interferes with another light in the bathroom. (turning it off and on)

Can anyone see what i've done wrong at a glance!?

[image]

Comment: sorry, there's 3 lights in the bathroom, the picture is of the 1st light in the chain, the third light will turn off if i turn on the first light...

Comment: Your metric for "exactly the way it was" appears to be inaccurate.

Comment: It is possible the other fixture was wired differently, check the symbols on the lugs , otherwise I agree with Harper.